# java 11 Unrecognized option: -xmx64m (Lowercase cmd and power shell options)

Tags: java, java-11

I looked up a combination of search terms and found that for a few people, java's option was converted to lowercase, just like me, in cmd or powershell, and sometimes it didn't work. The link below is the same case as mine, but I don't work on the powershell, unlike this case. Is there any way to solve this?

https://www.inflearn.com/questions/920520/%EC%9C%88%EB%8F%84%EC%9A%B0-%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%EC%9E%90%EB%B6%84%EB%93%A4-cmd%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%ED%86%B0%EC%BA%A3-%EC%98%A4%EB%A5%98-%ED%98%B9%EC%9D%80-%EB%B9%8C%EB%93%9C-%EC%98%A4%EB%A5%98-%EB%82%A0%EB%95%8C

I found out that there was a problem with java while using Android Studio.

If you go directly to the bin folder under jdk-11 in cmd and run java.exe to use jdk 11, the following message occurs. If you run the run button on the Android studio, Gradle will run normally, but it will not run on the terminal.

After testing in many ways, the above error occurs when running in cmd or powershell. Strangely, however, there is no problem with git bash.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin>java.exe -Xmx64m
Unrecognized option: -xmx64m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

```
java version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcThY.png)

But I ran it directly on cmd so I could see that for jdk17 in Android studio or for jdk 1.7 from a third party, the -Xmx64 option is fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW1n0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlkBi.png)

```
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231, mixed mode)
```

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Is the -Xmx64m option not available on jdk 11 by any chance?

I deleted all java and installed only 11.

Comment: That first command looks odd -- on OS X `java` preserves the case of command line arguments when reporting errors.

Comment: You should give a Java / Class file along with the memory option.

Comment: @ShriHariL That's not the issue here.

Comment: After testing in many ways, the above error occurs when running in cmd or powershell. Strangely, however, there is no problem with git bash. Is there anything else that needs to be changed?

Comment: @tgdavies That was a question for me, too. I definitely put in -Xmx64m that starts with a capital letter, but it actually changed to a lowercase letter. -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew is also lowercase, not just -Xmx. Is there a case setting for cmd or powershell?

Comment: So it's your shell that's doing the conversion to lowercase?

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes. If I run java.exe of jdk-11 on my cmd or powershell, it will be lowercase. Running 'java.exe -Xmx64m' in gitbash under the same conditions as cmd (go to bin folder with jdk11 Java) will work. And if you run 'java.exe -xmx64m' under the same conditions on git bash, the error 'Uncognized option: -xmx64m' attached above will be the same. So I think forced conversion from cmd or powershell to lowercase is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I spend 3 weeks and find a ridiculous solution and leave my own answers.

This problem was caused by another program. At one point, I had a vaccine program that I didn't install, and it was included as a launch app. As soon as I turned on the computer, I ran the command in cmd, and I was able to see that it was working properly. So I decided that there was a conflict in the startup program, so I tested it one by one and found the problem.(In my case, it was a program called Trojancut.)

If you're having a similar problem with me, or if you're having problems with Java itself, disable all of the startup programs and test them as soon as you turn on your computer, like me.